# How to create Pinyin character PNG with transparent backgrounds?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mac, character

We need to generate Chinese Pinyin Characters with transparent backgrounds for overlay in a video. We are trying to do this in photoshop but are unable to access the pinyin character set on a mac. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can add the 'ABC - Extended' input sources in the system preferences. Then you can type the Pinyin character easy with 'ABC - Extended'.

First type **option + `** and then type **o**, you will get the **ò**.

- **option + a** then type **a** => **ā**
- **option + e** then type **a** => **á**
- **option + v** then type **a** => **ǎ**
- **option + `** then type **a** => **à**
- **option + e** then type **v** => **ǘ**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely that you would be able to find a graphic on the 'net containing all of the characters you require. I performed a search and found compilation images that purport to be this. Download or otherwise capture one of these images and remove the background, followed by individual cropping of each character (or vice versa).

It would be mildly tedious, but would result in separate character images to be saved for your objective.